# Running a startup program in terminal with sudo

Tags: lubuntu, startup, root

I need to run a python script in a terminal, *myscript.py* at startup (on Lubunt). This script requires root.

I've set up a `.desktop` file that runs the following command:

```
lxterminal --command="python /home/d/Jarvis/alarm.py && /bin/bash"
```

The terminal window opens at startup and runs the script, but then closes when the Python script returns an error (because it's not being run as root). When I change the `Exec=` to this...

```
lxterminal --command="sudo python /home/d/Jarvis/alarm.py && /bin/bash"
```

... (prefixing command with `sudo`) which works. **However**, the terminal opens on startup and displays the

```
[sudo] password for d: \
```

prompt, requiring me to input my password. **I would like the execution of the python script at startup to be completely automatic with no user interaction.**

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it at login and not startup (as I don't see how LXTerminal can be opened without X server being up), you have to add an exception to the /etc/sudoers file so that you won't be prompted for your password.

To do this, run `sudo visudo` and then add the following:

```
<your username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/d/Jarvis/alarm.py
```

Make sure that you add this at the end of the file for this to work. I would also set the permissions of `alarm.py` to executable for this to work. So, do this to set it as executable:

```
chmod +x /home/d/Jarvis/alarm.py
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I still have one issue... When I run "alarm.py" instead of "python alarm.py", I get 'import: not found' errors for core python modules (ex. datetime). I don't think I'm able to copy those modules into /Jarvis/, so what do I do?

Comment: @Brandon You might have to set the `PYTHONPATH` variable, but this is just a guess. For this, I would create a script called 'alarm_starter.sh' with the following contents: `PYTHONPATH={what ever it should be} sudo /home/d/Jarvis/alarm.py`. I'm really not sure about this, though. Maybe this will help: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 9):

Custom scripts that get executed on startup as root can be run via `rc.local`.

Edit `/etc/rc.local` with root rights:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and put the line

```
python /home/d/Jarvis/alarm.py
```

just before the last line, which should say `exit 0`.
Reboot to see if it worked.

Comment: This solved my problem for autostarting programs on Raspbian.